# Panel Background Image Repetition C#

Tags: c#, image, panel

I want to place an image in a panel, but I do not want it repeated according to the size of the panel.

What I did is this:

```
panel3.BackgroundImage = picture1;
```

However, picture1 is repeated several times, since the panel is much wider than the actual picture.

What I want is to display the picture in its original form only.  I don't want it repeated.

How can I do this?  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
ImageLayout.Stretch; //make Image Fill the Control 
ImageLayout.None; //just put the image without any changes on size
ImageLayout.Center; //adjust location of image to be centered
ImageLayout.Tile; //repeat image
ImageLayout.Zoom; //re size image to be all viewed in the control (without stretch)
```

Answer (score 6):

try

```
panel3.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

this will stop repeatition and will stretch image to whole panel. If you don't want image to stretch Try `ImageLayout.Center`

Answer (score 1):

You can set `BackgroundImageLayout` to `Center`.